# Lock your computer after 5 minutes of inactivity

Tags: windows-7, security, user-accounts, access-control

I know you can automatically Sleep and Hibernate your computer with a timer. But these affect running programs and stop downloads ... so I was wondering if there is a way to automatically Lock your computer with a timer?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Go to control panel. Go to Appearance and Personalizations. Go to Screen Save Settings. Adjust wait  times as desired.
Setup a screen saver and check the box to "On resume, display logon screen"

If you want this password protected, setup your account to have a password.

Comment: Will a screensaver pause running of active programs (and downloads) ?

Comment: @Jeremy Rudd: No, it will not; it will simply lock the screen.

Comment: I want to change 15 minutes to 5 minutes but it's disabled "some settings are managed by your system administrator"

Answer (score 1):

What OS?

With Windows you can set your screensaver to turn on after X minutes and set that to require a password to unlock it.

Comment: Linux too, and most other *nixes